# ng-repeat not iterating over items in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and JavaScript for that matter. One tutorial that I'm working through is one of iterating over some names and for some reason it's just not working. Any suggestions on  what to do? Below is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning AngularJS: Controllers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The People App</h1>
    <h4>View People</h4>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            from ,
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MainCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.people = [{
                    name: 'John Doe',
                    city: 'New York City',
                    state: 'New York'
                },{
                    name: 'John Smith',
                    city: 'Oklahoma City',
                    state: 'Oklahoma'
                },{
                    name: 'Henry Black',
                    city: 'Topeka',
                    state: 'Kansas'
            }];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me (except that it doesn't print the names or something). Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Yes , you forgot to display the values: http://plnkr.co/edit/IsPY5EnUJUNEaKkiBviI?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output scope variables you have to use double curly bracket notation like this:

```
{{person}}
```

In your case, I do believe you want to get inner properties of a person like this:

```
{{ person.name }}
```

In your example, as I see, you want to display information like this:

```
John Doe from New York City
```

In order to do that, you have to use double curly bracket notation as [in this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dc5HZNtcdhbFgTFz7gy2?p=preview):

```
{{person.name}} from , {{person.city}}
```

In addition, you can use AngularJS filter "json" to see the list of people printed out as json like this:

```
{{ people | json  }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a noob error and a little embarrassing that I was attempting to have it load the data without telling it where to load it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.name}} {{person.city}} {{person.state}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to plug in the data to the template in this way:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.name}} from {{person.city}}, {{person.state}}
</li>
```